# How to establish a connection between peers based on COTURN server and using WebSockets only, without WebRTC

Tags: websocket, turn, coturn

I installed and configured a COTURN server in an EC2 instance. Then, I did some preliminary tests to check its operation using Trickle ICE. Everything works fine. Now I want to establish a communication between peers without using WebRTC, using only WebSockets. I don't know how to do that, all the tutorials I found use WebRTC.

I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction and give me some advice on how to use the COTURN server with WebSockets in NodeJS.

Comment: Are your clients expected to connect to a server using WebSockets? Is the data or media expected to flow through the WebSockets?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want my clients to connect to the coturn server using websocket and exchange data using these websockets created with the coturn server

Comment: That's not possible, AFAICT. coturn (see the [README](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/master/README.turnserver)) implements a list of RFCs, none of which define the use of a TURN server connecting over WebSocket. Your application can use coturn as a TURN server, and so access it over UDP or TCP, either encrypted or not.

Comment: If instead you want to use WebSockets as the transport for exchanging signalling, that's surely possible. With WebRTC you can use any signalling system, and so develop one that works over WebSockets. In that way your clients can exchange offer/answers and ICE candidates, and if configured properly, can use coturn to generate `relay` candidates.

Comment: Ok, I see now how it works, Thank you for these clarifications.

Comment: no worries; I've reformulated what we discussed as the answer of this question.

Comment: Is there any client side. turn library that i can use to communicate with turn server... peers can use tcp to connect to coturn,

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the comments thread in the question, I think the best answer is that the TURN service (provided by `coturn`) and the signalling service (implemented over WebSocket) are two separate things.

A WebRTC application can use TURN for discovering its `relay` candidates, and share them with another party over any signalling system, including something built with WebSockets.

Time ago [a proposal](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-chenxin-behave-turn-websocket-01.html) was made to use WebSocket as a transport for TURN, but it didn't become a standard and it's not supported by `coturn` (or any other TURN service I know).